# Entity Framework Core: generate duplicate column name in SQL

Tags: entity-framework, blazor

Code:

```
DbContext.Set<ContextEntity>().Include(t => t.Domain).ToListAsync();
```

Generate SQL command:

```
SELECT [c].[**Id**], [c].[DomainId], [c].[ParentId], [t].[**Id**], [t].[Code], [t].[Name], [t].[Usage]
FROM [Contexts] AS [c]
INNER JOIN [Termins] AS [t] ON [c].[DomainId] = [t].[Id]
```

Problem: duplicate column name **Id** and program error.

EF Core 3.1.0 or 3.1.1. Client: Blazor webassembly (preview).

Unit test is ok. An error occurs only when requesting from a client application...very strange.

Comment: Does the unit test and the app use the same database provider?  Can you produce a short, self-contained repro and include it in your question?

Comment: Blazor webassembly has no access to EF. The sentence _error occurs only when requesting from a client application_ is incomplete, it misses the *"through"*, how client request a remote EF execution? Through webapi maybe?

Comment: Of course, the client accesses data through WebApi. The versions of the libraries are the same. The trick is that the error only occurs when requested from a Blazor application.

Comment: For other data `Include` works correctly.